# Units of $F(x) = x-x^3$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, dimensional-analysis

If we are given that $F(x) = x-x^3$ is a force function, which means it is in the units of $[M][L][T]^{-2}$, then how do we determine what kind of "unit units" participate in this function?

Namely, we have: $[x-x^3]=[M][L][T]^{-2} \implies [x][1-x^2]=[M][L][T]^{-2}$, so we have unit mass $m$: $[m][x][1-x^2]=[M][L][T]^{-2}$. We also observe that the $[x]$ corresponds to $[L]$. Now, there should be $[T]^{-2}$ somewhere in LHS, so we can deduce something like this for a unit function of time $t$: $[m][x][1/t^2][1-x^2]=[M][L][T]^{-2}$ or $[m][a][1-x^2]=[M][L][T]^{-2}$, where $a$ is unit acceleration. We should also probably deduce that there is a unit of $[L]^{-2}$ before the $x^2$ in $[1-x^2]$, so we thus have $[m][a]([1]-[1/d^2][x^2])=[M][L][T]^{-2}$, where $1/d^2$ is some unit function of distance.

I think that I'm not quite correct in some of my reasoning, so I'd appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an algebraic expression, all terms which are added or subtracted must have the same dimensions. This implies that each term on the left-hand side of an equation must have the same dimensions as each term on the right-hand side.

So you have that $$
[F]=[x]=[x^3]=[M][L][T]^{-2}
$$
It's obvious thatt if $x$ and $x^3$ have the same dimension, there exist at least two unitary constant $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=1$ such that
$[\alpha x]=[\beta x^3]=[M][L][T]^{-2}$, that is
\begin{align}
[\alpha] [x]&=[M][L][T]^{-2}\\
[\beta] [x]^3&=[M][L][T]^{-2}
\end{align}
If you choose $x$ as lenght, that is $[x]=[L]$, you'll have $[\alpha]=[M][T]^{-2}$ and $[\beta]=[M][L]^{-2}[T]^{-2}$. If you choose $x$ as acceleration, that is $[x]=[L][T]^{-2}$, you'll have $[\alpha]=[M]$ and $[\beta]=[M][L]^{-2}[T]^{4}$. and so on.